# PHPmyadmin is returning 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in the date after importing

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, phpmyadmin

I am using sql to export data using the following code

```
select * from club
```

One of the column is a date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy hh/sec`

```
ID | Date
-----------------
1  | 4/8/2017 16:36
```

I need to import the extracted database into another server's phpmyadmin as datetime. When I use the import function in phpMyAdmin, it's setting all the date columns in the imported records to 0000-00-00 00:00:00, regardless of whether there's any value in the import file.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get the Datecolumn in the database to be set to `4/8/2017 16:36` instead of `0000-00-00 00:00:00?`

---

Response:

I have tried this but it gives null values in date

```
select idCustomer, msisdn, idOperator,  STR_TO_DATE(lastBilledDate,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i'), STR_TO_DATE(customerSince,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i'), pin, isValid, isBlocked
  from customer where customerSince between  '2017-04-01' and '2017-04-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your date is in a text format. If you want to keep it in this format, set a column in a new database as text. If you want convert it to MySQL date format:

```
SELECT id, STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%d/%m/%Y %h:%i') from table;
```

(assuming that the last number in your format is number of munutes)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it as you mentioned. please check my edit.

Comment: You have a date in a bad format. 4/8/2017 has one digit for month and day, it should be 04/08/2017. MySQL's STR_TO_DATE can recognize only 2-digit month and day. So you have to write some SQL function to convert date into correct format, or export your table to a text file and do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL datetime format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` so it will insert zeros if column type is set to datetime and format in import file is not correct.

Try to import datetime into temporary varchar column and then do update with converting string to date in real datetime column with `STR_TO_DATE`.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET real_datetime_column = STR_TO_DATE(temp_varchar_column, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i');
```